# How many proposers are selected during one epoch?

Tags: sharding, beacon-chain, the-merge, danksharding, eip-4844

Suppose there are enough validators(128 X 64 X 32). In one epoch, which one is true?

1. 64 x 32 proposers/ one proposer for each (shard, slot)
2. 32 proposers/ one proposer for each slot
3. 64 proposers/ one proposer for each shard

One more question, how many proposers are there in an epoch when there aren't enough validators(e.g. 128 X 40 X 32)?

Answer (score 0):

64 shards are now unlikely as "Danksharding" is the likely plan. Thus, **32 proposers in 1 epoch** will remain: one proposer for each slot.

> Danksharding is the new sharding design proposed for Ethereum, which introduces some significant simplifications compared to previous designs.

> ... instead of there being a fixed number of shards that each have distinct blocks and distinct block proposers, in Danksharding there is only one proposer that chooses all transactions and all data that go into that slot

References:

- https://notes.ethereum.org/@vbuterin/proto_danksharding_faq
- https://old.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/vrx9xe/ama_we_are_ef_research_pt_8_07_july_2022

Answer (score 0):

In Ethereum's proof-of-stake mechanism, a total of 20 validators, known as proposers, are selected to create new blocks during each epoch.